# Two laser diodes beat frequency

Tags: interference, laser-diode

With a single laser diode, the interference pattern of the light with itself gives a beat frequency of zero.

Given two laser diodes (same wavelength, same manufacturer), the interference pattern of both lights should give a beat frequency of zero, but probably it would be different.

Could a photo diode detect this non-zero beat frequency? In practice, there are commodity prescalers up to 10 GHz. So there is another question: How to choose a manufacturer (of laser diodes) where the interference beat frequency could be less than 10GHz.

For instance, as an application , an OCXO is a very stable oscillator. Could this pair of LDs be as stable as that (if all this concept is correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's possible to design a laser diode with very narrow linewidth (on the order of kHz), typical commercial devices will have much wider lindewidth, probably on the order of GHz, at least, depending on the intended application and the device geometry.

The center frequency is also not always very well defined, if that isn't required for the application. For a low cost CD laser, or even a datacomm communication laser, the center frequency could vary by 10's or even 100's of GHz without affecting the performance of the laser in the system. The center frequency may also drift by many gigahertz over temperature. On the other hand a laser intended for DWDM communication might need to have its center wavelength specified to within a couple of GHz to be in the correct WDM channel. Even then you would be very lucky to find a pair of devices with center frequencies matched to within, say 1 MHz.

That means when you beat two laser diodes together, even if they are nominally identical, you are likely to get a beat frequency of GHz or 10's of GHz, and it is likely to drift with temperature. And the beat signal may be essentially a noise signal spanning several GHz.

If you want to use the beat of two laser diodes as a reference tone source, you need to choose lasers specially to have tightly controlled center frequency and narrow linewidths. The easiest way to do this for a one-off experiment is to use an external cavity laser diode. That is, a laser that uses a diode structure as the gain medium, but uses external mirrors or gratings, rather than features on the chip, as the feedback mechanism. As a bonus, external cavity lasers are easily tuned to a desired frequency by adjusting the external mirrors or gratings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found some external cavity lasers, at web stores. Now I have several issues to study, before asking again.